# Bibliography in LaTeX: Spaces between words

Tags: spacing, bibtex, bibliographies

I'm writing the bibliography. LaTeX don't write it well. I don't know why. I have tried the two methods: `\begin{the bibliography}` and using BiBTeX. The result is the same.

The result is longer spaces between some words.

[image]

Using the first method(without BibTeX). The first entry at the image is:

```
\bibitem{Stack1}
Stack Overflow. \tit{Simple Bluetooth data receiver Android}. \url{http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164138/simple-bluetooth-data-receiver-android}.
```

`\tit{}` is like `\textit{}`

I have written a small example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left=1.8in,right=1.8in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry}


\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Dani}
Daniel García. \textit{Activando y desactivando el bluetooth en Android}. \url{http://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/bluetooth-i-activando-y-desactivando-el-bluetooth-en-android/}.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

And the result is

[image]

Comment: Your hyperlinks/urls aren't broken down. If you are using package `hyperref` and the option `breaklinks`, or use package `url`.

Comment: In the screenshot you are citing `stackoverflow` a few times, but not a single time `tex.stackexchange.com` I hope this is just hidden on the next page ;-)

Comment: Johannes_B I don't understand your solution. I'm usign \url

Comment: Ok, Kurt. I have added a small example and the result.

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\UrlBreaks}{\do\-}{}{}` You can read more about it in the documentation of package `url`

Answer (score 14):

Your URL string contains quite a few `-` (hyphen) characters, and it's quite long. By default, URL strings are *not* broken at hyphenation characters. To enable line breaking at the hyphens, load the `url` package with the option `hyphens` *before* loading `hyperref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.8in,vmargin=0.6in]{geometry}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  %% be sure to specify the option 'hyphens'
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Dani}
Daniel García. \textit{Activando y desactivando el bluetooth en Android}. 
    \url{http://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/bluetooth-i-activando-y-desactivando-el-bluetooth-en-android/}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

---

***Addendum, May 2023***: In the almost nine years that have passed since I wrote the answer shown above, (at least) three important developments have occurred in LaTeX land that call for revising my earlier answer mildly.

First, the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package has been written. It modifies the older [url](https://ctan.org/pkg/url) package to allow line breaks *anywhere* in a URL string, not just at period (aka full stops), hyphen, and space characters. With the advent of this package, URL strings protruding into the right-hand margin are a thing of the past.

Second, the input encoding `utf8` has been declare to be the default. Hence, the instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is redundant/unnecessary.

Third, the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package has become very good at detecting how it should configure its routines to maximize its interoperability with the TeX engine -- pdftex, luatex, xetex, or something else. Hence, it's actually something of a *bad idea* to specify the option `pdftex`. In short: Don't specify the `pdftex` option, as it can do no good but can, in fact, do some harm.

Here's how the output of the previous MWE looks like when I make the recommended adjustments. The effect of the first one (using `xurl` instead of `url` is clearly visible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  %%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\else
  % \usepackage{fontspec} % or: \usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi

\usepackage[hmargin=1.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xurl} %% not "\usepackage[hyphens]{url}"
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks]{hyperref} % don't use 'pdftex' option

\begin{document}
\raggedright

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{Dani}
Daniel García. \textit{Activando y desactivando el bluetooth en Android}. 
    \url{http://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/bluetooth-i-activando-y-desactivando-el-bluetooth-en-android/}.
    
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

After loading `hyperref` with the `breaklinks` option, add the hyphen to the list of allowed break points by doing

```
\g@addto@macro\UrlBreaks{\do\-}
```

You can also relax the spacing of the bibliography by adding `\raggedright` before it. This aligns the following text in the current group flush left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlBreaks{\do\-}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Dani}
  Daniel García. \textit{Activando y desactivando el bluetooth en Android}. \url{http://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/bluetooth-i-activando-y-desactivando-el-bluetooth-en-android/}.
\end{thebibliography}

\begingroup
\raggedright
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Dani}
  Daniel García. \textit{Activando y desactivando el bluetooth en Android}. \url{http://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/bluetooth-i-activando-y-desactivando-el-bluetooth-en-android/}.
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image]