# Reference about an online resource without author name

Tags: bibliographies

I want to cite a reference about an onlien resource without an author name. My problem is exactly similar to the problem mentioned at [this SO post][1] but the solution there is not working for me.

I am putting the online reference as follows:

```
@online{memAccess,
  title = {Online reference about the section.},
  url = {http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-memory-accesses},
  urldate = {2015-09-08}
}
```

but by putting the reference in ***that way shows only the title*** of the reference in the bibliogrphy, ***I want the it to show other information*** also like the URL, date on which it is accessed.

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
%\documentclass[12pt, hyphens]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  %% be sure to specify the option 'hyphens'
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=425.196850394pt, top=70.866141732pt,bottom=70.866141732pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{\rightmark}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%%%----------for bibliogtrapy to appear in the table of contents------%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\csname phantomsection\endcsname\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}}{}{}
\title{         
        {\large Company Name} \\[1.5in]
        {This is the title of the report}\\[1.5in] %Computation at GPU
    }
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Document Begins from here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

% Include the chapters of the thesis, as separate files
\input{Chapters/1_introduction} % Introduction


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------bibliography
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  
\backmatter
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}  % Change the left side page header to "Bibliography"
\bibliographystyle{plain}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography
\bibliography{Chapters/biblio} 



\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't seem to use `biblatex` although you tagged your question with that tag. As far as I can see, the style `plain.bst` that you use does not support the `url` and `urldate` field. (The two are supported by `biblatex` and at least `url` is supported by newer styles such as `plainurl`).  Unfortunately your MWE contains too much code not relate to the issue at hand (`\renewcommand*\env@matrix`, `\input`s where we don't have the files, `graphicx`, ...), please make it truly minimal.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. The few things I mentioned in my comment were just examples, you can get rid of much more things than that. It would probably be enough if the `documentclass` and just about `\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Chapters/biblio}` were left standing, most of the other stuff can be discarded. Please see [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a biblatex entry type, while using just simple bibtex.

To solve it add the following lines in your preamble:

```
 \usepackage[style=<name of your style>, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{<name of your bib file>.bib} % This line is neccesary if the name is different than the name of your main file
```

Then, replace the lines the following lines:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography
\bibliography{Chapters/biblio}
```

By:

```
\printbibliography
```

For a list of available styles see either the [documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) or a [list of available styles](https://www.ctan.org/topic/biblatex) on CTAN.

Furthermore, in general you should at least once use the citation to show it in the bibliography. Unused citations by default are not displayed. As such add `\cite{memAccess}` somewhere in your text.

Example output with style `alphabetic`:

[image]

---

## Alternatively, you could just go with plain BibTex:

In that case, add the `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble to make the clickable url.

And change your bibresource for example in the following way:

```
@Misc{memAccess,
   Title                    = {Online reference about the section.},
   HowPublished             = {\url{http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/\#device-memory-accesses}},
   Note                     = {Accessed: 2015-09-08},

   Url                      = {http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-memory-accesses},
}
```

The result with your `plain` style:

[image]

To remove the ugly colored links, change the `hyperref` package line to the following:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
```

With `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` and `\raggedright`before bibliography:

[image]

Comment: It throws an error: `! Package biblatex Error: File 'Report_Work.bbl' not created by biblatex`; where "Report_Work" is the name of my report.

Comment: I added an alternative. However, you can fix that error by running the `bibliography`/`bibtex` command once.

Comment: It worked but there is unusual spacing among the words of the title. Actually the original title should be "Device memory access" and there is too much space among these three words. Can I do somethign for that?

Comment: That's a different problem, which is caussed by the urls. For solutions, please see [this question.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200333/bibliography-in-latex-spaces-between-words)

Comment: that answer suggests to use `\usepackage[hypens]{url}` but when I try to use it I get the error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package url.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.15 \usepackage
{subcaption}
The package url has already been loaded with options:
[]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[hyphens]
Adding the global options:
,hyphens
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.`

Comment: Did you load the url package before or after the hyperref package, because the url should be before. Furthermore, do you actually load the subcaption package, because it doesn't seems to be the case in the code you provided in your question? However, you can just try what the error suggests; add the hyphens option to the global options. So add the option to your document class. So `\documentclass[12pt, hyphens]{scrbook}`.

Comment: I have changed the position of `\usepackage[hypens]{url}` near the top and that does not throw any error. But the problem of unusual spacing is still there.

Comment: You should look at all the anwsers in that question. The one, which gives immedaitely the best result is by placing `\raggedright` before `\bibliography`. I added how it looks at my end with both the `hypens`option and the `\raggedright`. You also could try the `\g@addto@macro\UrlBreaks{\do\-}` with the `breaklinks` option in the hyperref package.