# Excessive white space in bibliography entry

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am struggling with excessive white space in my bibliography entry. This question has been [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200333/bibliography-in-latex-spaces-between-words) [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360130/bibliography-spaces-between-words-when-using-url), but the commonly prescribed advice of including the hyphens option of the `url` package before `hyperref` is not working for me.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike} 
    \bibliography{mini}
    \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

and my file mini.bib

```
@misc{feilden2017,
  title = {Most Scientists 'Can't Replicate Studies'},
  abstract = {Science is facing a "reproducibility crisis" as scientists fail to reproduce others' work, it is claimed.},
  language = {en-GB},
  howpublished = {\url{https://web.archive.org/web/20190413132210/https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-39054778}},
  author = {Feilden, Tom},
  month = feb,
  year = {2017}
}
```

The result looks like:
[image]

Comment: you could set your bibliography `\raggedright` or set up url to allow breaking anywhere not just at `/` etc

Comment: Try loading the `xurl` package, to have more breaking points for urls

Comment: I am using a Wiley template and
\usepackage[sectionbib,numbers,sort]{natbib}% for numbered citation comment the above line \usepackage{hyperref} """
""" etc
\incliude(ch01)
""
""etc
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{wiley}
\latexprintindex \end{document} and in wiley.bib
@misc{SF1,
author = {foo},
title = {bar},
year = {2023},
url = {https://foo{\_}overflow.txt},
note = {Accessed: 26/8/23}
} I had to press the biBTex button several times and to quick build several times to get a stable bibliography. Thank you for posting!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Bernard has already suggested in a comment, you should replace

```
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
```

with

```
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{xurl}
```

Loading the `xurl` package instead of the `url` package allows URL strings to be line-broken not just a hyphen and space (and slash) characters, but at *any* character. I would still specify the option `obeyspaces`, though, as otherwise space characters in URL strings will be suppressed entirely.

As an entirely welcome byproduct of using `xurl`, the unsightly whitespace gaps in other parts of the typeset bib entries will vanish automatically.

Oh, the `xurl` package is of fairly recent vintage; this probably explains why you couldn't find it mentioned in the early posting you've referenced in your query.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mini.bib}
@misc{feilden2017,
  title = {Most Scientists `Can't Replicate Studies'},
  abstract = {Science is facing a ``reproducibility 
      crisis'' as scientists fail to reproduce others' 
      work, it is claimed.},
  language = {en-GB},
  howpublished = {\url{https://web.archive.org/web/20190413132210/https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-39054778}},
  author = {Feilden, Tom},
  month = feb,
  year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{xurl}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mini}    
\end{document}
```